# PHP - Unable to echo out values in returned array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, pdo

I have a function that retrieves data from a Mysql database, stores the values in an array and returns that array to the calling function.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT img_file_name FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_active = 0 AND post_id = ? ");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$post_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $resultarray = array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $resultarray[] = $row;
        }

        return $resultarray;
```

I am attempting to echo out the $values within that array like this:

```
$resultarray = get_post_data($post_id);

print_r($resultarray);

foreach($resultarray as $key => $value){
    echo 'The value is: '. $value . '<br />';
}
```

But when I browse the webpage it is only echoing out "Array".
When I print_r the array the values are definitely in the array. So how do I correctly display those values?

Comment: depends on array structure, loop through it as you do with foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
$resultarray[] = $row;
```

with this:

```
$resultarray[] = $row['img_file_name'];
```

Comment: The result of his `print_r` is ok, but the result of his `echo` is `Array`.

Answer (score 4):

Makes sense. when you save `$row` to your array, you're actually creating a 2d array. `$row` is an array, even though you only selected one value. If you only want to save the image file name you selected, save `$row['img_file_name']` to the array, instead if `$row`.

Alternatively, echo `$value['img_file_name']` instead of `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($resultarray as $row){
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
        echo 'The value is: '. $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```